# webpack: when using 2 entry files, both files include the same css - is there a workaround?

Tags: webpack-4

I use 2 entry files, `startpage.js` and `subpage.js`, and assign them successfully to their HTML files via the `HTMLWebpackPlugin`s chunks parameter.

But since that solution requires to include the CSS files in both the `startpage.js` and `subpage.js`, which makes for "double the trouble" (at least during the build process), I decided to create another file, `app_head`, and put the `import 'main.css'` statement there. (And I also have a `vendor` file that should be placed in the header of the HTML, which should happen by adding `_head` according to the documentation: `https://github.com/architgarg/html-webpack-injector` - but that does not work either...)

This is the current webpack config (excerpt):

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app_head: './src/css/main.css',
    vendor_head: './src/scripts/vendor/_all_vendor.js',
    startpage: './src/scripts/startpage.js',
    subpage: './src/scripts/subpage.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/templates/index.ejs',
      chunks: ['app_head', 'vendor_head', 'startpage'],
      chunksConfig: {
        defer: ['startpage']
      },
      excludeChunks: ['subpage'],
      bodyCss: 'is-startpage',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'publication.html',
      template: './src/templates/publication.ejs',
      chunks: ['subpage'],
      chunksConfig: {
        defer: ['subpage']
      },
      excludeChunks: ['startpage'],
      bodyCss: 'is-subpage',
    }),
    [...]
```

The `app_head.css` is placed properly in the head section of the HTML, but it also generates a useless `app_head.js`, which only contains webpack code. Unfortunately, I do not know of any way how to exclude that file without also excluding the CSS.

Is there a better way to separate the CSS generation process without producing overhead or garbage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you did not initialized the html-webpack-injector plugin.

```js
// import above
const HtmlWebpackInjector = require('html-webpack-injector');

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(...),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(...),
    new HtmlWebpackInjector() // add this in plugins array
```

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for proofreading – highly appreciated!!!